# Why does [web-api] redirect to [asp.net-web-api]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I attempted to re-tag a question to enlist the help of folks more experienced with web-api security at [How to prevent clients from retrieving my server's certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45366087/608639).

After selecting [web-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-api), it was changed to [asp.net-web-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api).

It seems like claiming all Web APIs are ASP.NET-based APIs is a bit of a stretch. It seems like one of two things should occur:

1. Stop redirecting [web-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-api) to [asp.net-web-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api) since not all Web APIs are .NET-based APIs.
2. Delete [web-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-api) since it's ambiguous or incorrect. That is, selecting it results in unexpected behavior.

Comment: Indeed, I tried to change it to web-api and it flipped back to asp.net-web-api. Never seen that before myself.

Comment: ASP.Net web API is often just called "WebAPI".  It's really the name of the product.  I agree the tag probably shouldn't re-direct, however, I wonder how useful a generic `web-api` tag would actually be?

Comment: @silencedmessage - Thanks for the info on *WebAPI*. I don't work with it enough to know its a trade name. I might be splitting hairs, but *WebAPI* is a product name or trade name and it should probably have its own tag. *web-api* is a technology, and Microsoft's implementation is not the only embodiment of the technology.

Comment: @jww I agree! (Sorry my comment wasn't more clear).  I guess I'm supporting removing the tag all together, as I question if there'd be any benefit to a generalized `web-api` tag.

Comment: The "why" is because they are synonyms https://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net-web-api/synonyms. I don't see any option to unsynonymise them though. Maybe it requires a certain tag score.

Comment: @MartinSmith well... https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230967/213575

Comment: @BhargavRao How was this "completed"? Was the synonym removed? Was `web-api` deleted? Would be nice to get some clarification.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I'm probably heading to bed in a few minutes, so will not be able to add an answer. The Tl;Dr is, [web-api] and [asp.net-web-api] were both completely merged and synonymized in 2013, so [web-api] had 0 posts. Just deleting the synonym was enough to cater to both 1 and 2. [There are some 7k posts to review, most of which are asp.net api](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20%5basp.net-web-api%5d%20-%22ASP.NET%22%20-%22c%23%22%20-%22.net%22%20-%22Microsoft%22%20-%5bc%23%5d%20-%5basp.net%5d%20-%5basp.net-mvc%5d%20-%5basp.net-core%5d%20-%5b.net-core%5d&mixed=0).

Comment: Thanks for the info @BhargavRao!

Comment: No worries, @HereticMonkey. The lesson for me here is to not handle tag requests on meta while in a meeting or in any position where I can't add a quick answer/comment about the action taken.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, [web-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-api) is indeed ambiguous, even if it is called by the community exactly this way. The tag [asp.net-web-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api) describes it much better.

But for using it as a generic placeholder for some API, that communictates over the web, I think this tag is way too broad.

I propose the following:

1. [Review all questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api+-c%23+-asp.net), that are not tagged with [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) or [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) and retag it (if needed) to a product specifc tag instead. Do **not** retag it with [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api), since this tag is way too broad.
2. Remove [web-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-api) and maybe blacklist it.

Comment: You probably want [`asp.net-web-api` not `c#` not `asp.net` not `asp.net-mvc` not `asp.net-core` not `.net-core`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api%20not%20c%23%20not%20asp.net%20not%20asp.net-mvc%20not%20asp.net-core%20not%20.net-core). And that's still 9K questions to review.

Comment: Wow, I have seen only 1000, but now I noticed I was only on frequent tab Oo @CodeCaster. Theoreticaly, I stay with my answer. But now I see, it is not practicable :/